# Using a custom attribute in EF7 (core) OnModelCreating

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have a `DefaultAttribute` defined like so:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class DefaultAttribute : Attribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies this property has a default value upon creation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="defaultValue">The default value of the property.</param>
    /// <param name="useAsLiteral">Set to true if the value is <em>not</em> quoted in the DDL.</param>
    public DefaultAttribute(object defaultValue, bool useAsLiteral = false)
    {
        DefaultValue = defaultValue;
        UseAsLiteral = useAsLiteral;
    }

    public object DefaultValue { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// True if the default value is not quoted in the DDL
    /// </summary>
    public bool UseAsLiteral { get; private set; }
}
```

I have decorated several of my entities with this attribute, like so:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    . . . (other properties) . . .
    [StringLength(200)]
    [Required]
    [Default("My Default Description!")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in my OnModelCreating method in my database context, I wrote the following code:

```
//examine custom annotations for shaping the schema in the database.
foreach (var entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
    {
        var annotations = property.GetAnnotations();

        // evaluate default values
        var defaultAnnotation = annotations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == typeof(DefaultAttribute).FullName);
        if (defaultAnnotation != null)
        {
            var defaultValue = defaultAnnotation.Value as DefaultAttribute;
            if (defaultValue == null) continue;

            if (defaultValue.UseAsLiteral)
                property.Npgsql().DefaultValueSql = defaultValue.DefaultValue.ToString();
            else
                property.Npgsql().DefaultValue = defaultValue.DefaultValue;
        }
    }
```

My expectation, when adding a migration, (and subsequent database update) is that there would be a default value of "My Default Description!" for the `Description` column of `MyEntity`... however, that is not the case.

I'm not getting any errors, but it's not doing as I would suspect, and stepping into `OnModelCreating` with a breakpoint is also inexplicably difficult to do.

Am I doing this correctly?  Does it just not work?  Is it just not supported in EF7?  Or is it not supported in my PostgreSQL implementation?  Any insight would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Using @IvanStoev's answer, I was able to get this to work with some minor modifiactions (Reflection in .NET Core a bit different from traditional):

```
//examine custom annotations for shaping the schema in the database.
foreach (var entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
    {
        var memberInfo = property.PropertyInfo ?? (MemberInfo)property.FieldInfo;
        var defaultValue = memberInfo?.GetCustomAttribute<DefaultAttribute>();
        if (defaultValue == null) continue;
        if (defaultValue.UseAsLiteral)
            property.Npgsql().DefaultValueSql = defaultValue.DefaultValue.ToString();
        else
            property.Npgsql().DefaultValue = defaultValue.DefaultValue;
    }
```

This worked like a champ.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EF Core knows nothing about your custom attribute, so there is no way it to be discovered and exposed as annotation (which in general is a different thing and not necessarily associated with attribute).

You have to extract the attribute manually from `PropertyInfo` or `FieldInfo` when present:

```
foreach (var entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
    {
        var memberInfo = property.PropertyInfo ?? (MemberInfo)property.FieldInfo;
        if (memberInfo == null) continue;
        var defaultValue = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(memberInfo, typeof(DefaultAttribute)) as DefaultAttribute;
        if (defaultValue == null) continue;
        if (defaultValue.UseAsLiteral)
            property.Npgsql().DefaultValueSql = defaultValue.DefaultValue.ToString();
        else
            property.Npgsql().DefaultValue = defaultValue.DefaultValue;
    }
```

Comment: Note that there's no real reason to do `.Npgsql()` - that's for setting the default value only for Npgsql, when targeting multiple databases. In most cases you should simply do `property.HasDefaultValue(...)` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-values)